# ParseUser getCurrentUser() - if there is no current user?

Tags: android, parse-platform

The documentation says that returns the logged in ParseUser with valid session. But if there is no current logged user, what does it return? I don't see specified in documentation.

```
/**
 * This retrieves the currently logged in ParseUser with a valid session, either from memory or
 * disk if necessary.
 *
 * @return The currently logged in ParseUser
 */
 public static ParseUser getCurrentUser() {
    return getCurrentUser(isAutomaticUserEnabled());
 }
```

Comment: Maybe just null

Comment: I think you're right. Reading the documentation for `logOutInBackground()` it says _Logs out the currently logged in user session. This will remove the session from disk, log out of linked services, and future calls to ParseUser.getCurrentUser() will return null._. Thank you @DakshAgrawal.